# Trying to create a JSON in php with an Image as URL and create an ID to each image

Tags: php

Trying to create a **json encode with a ID and a image URL** so i can reach it as a jobject in my frontend.

I am not working with a MySQL here as I store the images on my map/file manager.

I want it to look like this when when the code runs:

```
{
  results: [
  {
  ID: "3",
  URL: "http://www.image.com/Images/image3.jpg"
  }        ]
}
```

So I want to connect an image to a certain IP and also get its URL.

This is my code so far:

```
<?php 

    $contacts = array();

          $contact = array("URL" => $row ['http://www.image.com/Images/image1.jpg'],
          $row ['http://www.image.com/Images/image2.jpg'],
          $row ['http://www.image.com/Images/image3.jpg'],
          "ID" => $row ['1'], $row ['2'], $row ['3']);
          array_push($contacts, $contact);


    echo json_encode(array('results' => $contacts), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still don't see $row.. Anyway, I think what you want is something like this :

```
<?php

    $contacts = array();

    $contacts[] = array("id"=>1,"URL"=>'http://www.image.com/Images/image1.jpg');
    $contacts[] = array("id"=>1,"URL"=>'http://www.image.com/Images/image2.jpg');
    $contacts[] = array("id"=>1,"URL"=>'http://www.image.com/Images/image3.jpg');

    echo json_encode(array('results' => $contacts), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Example https://3v4l.org/uRbQ7